# .NET MVC Core view not binding results to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have been unable to get the posted form values from the view to bind to the controller as it seems to return null in the ViewModel despite the contents of the post request being sent through. I have included the contents of the View and Controller as I'm assuming I must be missing something simple as I'm fairly new to .NET MVC.

### View

```
  @model IEnumerable<MyPortal.ViewModels.SubscriptionsViewModel>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Subscriptions";
    }
    <h2>Subscriptions</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset3">
            <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by [Name or [ID]" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" id="results">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset3">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>MemberID</th>
                    <th>SubscriptionRef</th>
                    <th>SubType</th>
                    <th>StartDate</th>
                    <th>EndDate</th>
                    <th>PrimaryPays</th>
                    <th>Save</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr class="searchResultRow">
                    @*
                    <input type="hidden" name="SubscriptionRef" value="@item.SubscriptionRef" />*@
                    @*
                    <td>@item.MemberID</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@item.SubscriptionRef</td>
                    <td>@item.SubType</td>
                    <td>@item.StartDate</td>
                    <td>@item.EndDate</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Html.CheckBox("PrimaryPaysInd", "PrimaryPaysIndBool") @item.PrimaryPaysInd @item.PrimaryPaysIndBool</td>*@
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("save", "secure", FormMethod.Post, new { redeemTransaction = Model }))
                    {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SubscriptionRef)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MemberID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubscriptionRef)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubType)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.PrimaryPaysIndBool)</td>
                    <td asp-for="PrimaryPaysInd">@item.PrimaryPaysInd</td>

                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" name="save" value="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button></td>
                    }
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset3">
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Controller

```
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using MyPortal.ViewModels;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
        using MyPortal.Models;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        using AutoMapper;
        namespace MyPortal.Controllers
        {
        public class SecureController : Controller
        {
            private ILogger _logger;
            private PortalContext _context;

            public SecureController(ILogger<SecureController> logger, PortalContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
                _logger = logger;
            }

            public ActionResult Search([FromForm]SubscriptionsViewModel subscriptions)
            {
                var searchParam = subscriptions.searchParam;
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }

            public IEnumerable<SubscriptionsViewModel> GetAllSubscriptionsById()
            {
                return (from s in _context.Subscriptions
                        where s.MemberID == 123
                        select new SubscriptionsViewModel
                        {
                            MemberID = s.MemberID,
                            SubTypeID = s.SubTypeID,
                            SubscriptionRef = s.SubscriptionRef,
                            StartDate = s.StartDate,
                            EndDate = s.EndDate,
                            PrimaryPaysInd = s.PrimaryPaysInd
                        }).Take(15).ToList();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult save([FromForm]SubscriptionsViewModel reedemTransaction)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("******************");
                _logger.LogInformation("EXECUTING POST");
                _logger.LogInformation("******************");
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var newSubscription = Mapper.Map<Subscription>(reedemTransaction);
                    _logger.LogInformation("***********************");
                    _logger.LogInformation("SubscriptionRef: " + reedemTransaction.SubscriptionRef);
                    _logger.LogInformation("PrimaryPaysInd: " + reedemTransaction.PrimaryPaysInd);
                    _logger.LogInformation("************************");
                    return RedirectToAction("subscription", "secure");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("index", "secure");
            }      
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have no name or id on the input of your form, how is it supposed to know what to bind?

Comment: also your form doesn't specify any action or controller

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific: The search form hasn't been fully implemented but I left it in for lack of brevity. The form I'm referring to is actually the second one where I'm "saving" and posting the update to subscription records.

Comment: not sure why you are using the old Html.BeginForm instead of using a regular form element, but each property of your model must be represented by a posted element with a name/id that corresponds to the property name for the model binder to be able to bind it. you can't pass the whole Model as a single parameter

Comment: I was using the Html.BeginForm from swapping and changing example code in my attempts to get it to work. @JoeAudette is there a way to force it to bind with out parsing through all of the properties? I also noticed that the way the params are being posted is prefixed with item (e.g. item.SubscriptionRef) as the record is being posted from an inline save button from an IEnumerable of the SubscriptionsViewModel class, is this likely preventing the controller from binding the returned parameters?

Comment: 1. Please clarify your question, the tags are ambiguous at best (mixes ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core and Text mentions MVC4). Please clear up the tags and make it clear if you use ASP.NET Core MVC or ASP.NET MVC. They are different frameworks and not compatible with each other as ASP.NET Core is a complete platform independent port and ASP.NET is the old legacy webstack which is designed and tied to IIS. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging _You should not force a tag into your title_

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tseng. I have removed any reference to the MVC4 article and the suggestions form that article which I had tried to alter and use in my attempts to get my solution working.under Core 1.0.

Comment: every property that needs to bind from your model must be represented in the html as an input or hidden input with an id/name matching the property names on the model. form element cannot wrap a tr element inside a table, that is invalid html, either do way with the table or make a separate table for each item so the entire table can be wrapped in the form not parts of the table, that will not render valid html markup